# How to get data from cloud firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm trying to figure out how to read data from my cloud firestore.

I have a database rule that says:

```
// Demo projects
    match /project/{projectId} {
      allow read;
      allow write;
    }
```

Then, I'm trying to use [react firestore hooks](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/master/firestore) to read the data.

I have

```
import { useDocument } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';
import { fsDB, firebase, settings } from "../../../../../firebase";



const Overview = props => {    
  const { state } = useStateMachine(updateAction);
  const [value, loading, error] = useDocument(
    firebase.firestore().doc('hooks/kN7ZOK5HRmDs5KhKTYSb'),
    {
      snapshotListenOptions: { includeMetadataChanges: true },
    }
  );
  return (
    <div>

        <Paragraph>
        <h2 style={{color: '#213159'}}>
        <p>
        {error && <strong>Error: {JSON.stringify(error)}</strong>}
        {loading && <span>Document: Loading...</span>}
        {value && <span>Document: {JSON.stringify(value.data())}</span>}
      </p>
```

This seems to work because an error message gets generated saying:

> Error: {"code":"permission-denied","name":"FirebaseError"}

My project table has all read and write permissions set to true (while I figure out how to get this working).

Can anyone see what else is necessary to read data from cloud firestore?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you might need to change those rules to `allow read: if true; allow write: if true`.

Comment: the docs don't require the if statement. Also, I've been able to write to the database using the approach I setup, so the if statement doesn't seem necessary

Answer (score 0):

Your rules aren't complete, but I'm assuming you've just given us an excerpt of something that looks more like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
// Demo projects
    match /project/{projectId} {
      allow read;
      allow write;
    } 
  }
}
```

If so, you are looking up a document `hooks/kN7ZOK5HRmDs5KhKTYSb` that doesn't match this rule (which wouldn't match anything under `hooks`), so the read will be denied.

If you need to allow a read to `hooks/kN7ZOK5HRmDs5KhKTYSb`, your rules probably want to look like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /hooks/{hookId} {
      allow read;
      allow write;
    } 
  }
}
```

You should be able to [use the simulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator) to quickly validate rules to see if they do what you expect.  Place the document you want to test a read for in the "location" field of the simulator.

The simulator can also help you find which particular line is allowing or denying a request, but it won't really help in your current situation since there isn't any rule that matches the `hooks/...` path at all, so no lines will match.

Comment: the example from the react-firestore-hooks documentation shows this pattern. I can't tell whether I'm supposed to map through hooks or some other way. At this point, I don't care if I stop trying to figure out react-firestore-hooks, but I can't find a way to get the document path from the simulator either.

Comment: The problem is that you've passed a reference that your rules are denying.  I don't see anything in the firestore hooks documentation that says you have to use that reference, but I'll admit I haven't looked that hard (even if it did, you could still enable that in the rules.  I've added such sample rules to the answer).  The simulator should have a pretty obvious box to put the document reference you want to test in.

Comment: i have tested the document number - but it doesn't help me figure out how to use that reference in hooks in react. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If changing the rules to what I posted still shows the permission denied error, please update your original post with your complete set of security rules.